# Handling signals under Emacs shell and Cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, cygwin

I use the Cygwin version of Emacs. Things are just fine except for some quirks when using the Emacs shell (M-x shell). The Emacs shell is using Cygwin's bash. The biggest problem right now is not being able to send a SIGINT to the shell to interrupt the currently running command. For example, I frequently use ssh to logon to a remote host, then "tail -f" a file. I can't break out of the tail command. When using the Emacs shell under Unix/Linux, pressing C-c C-c (comint-interrupt-subjob) will send SIGINT to the shell (bash), and the tail command (or whatever) will be interrupted as expected.

For a quick and easy example, run "M-x shell", then "sleep 30", and try to interrupt the sleep command. You can Quit (C-g) and do other things within Emacs, but the Emacs shell is hung for the duration of the sleep command.

I have a feeling this has something to do with the difference in signal sending/handling within Cygwin, as opposed to signals within Unix. Since the Cygwin bash shell responds appropriately to signals, I have to assume there is some way to get Emacs to send a SIGINT to the bash shell in a way that it understands. Any ideas?

By the way, I have used Emacs eshell, term and ansi-term, but I prefer shell for a number of reasons. I also use mintty and GNU Screen, and have no complaints there, but using Emacs shell and treating my terminal sessions like text files is a wonderful thing.

Comment: `C-c C-c` works for me with Cygwin/bash/xemacs.

Comment: Ah yes, C-c C-c works correctly in XEmacs (which is version 21). Thank you for pointing this out. I was hoping to get it to work with GNU Emacs 23.2.

Comment: Looks like it is a (long standing one at it) bug you have hit.  (http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-10/msg00437.html).  This bug got to be fixed.  Till then, what features would you miss by, say, using eshell in the place of shell?

Comment: @vpit3833 FWIW, that bug is fixed in the latest http://cygwin.com/snapshots and hence the upcoming Cygwin 1.7.8.

Comment: @ak2 if that bug is the cause for the behaviour described in the question, then the answer for the question might be to upgrade to the most recent edition of Cygwin

Comment: @vpit3833 - I don't think I would miss any features by using eshell instead.  However, if I ssh to a remote host from within eshell, and then press C-c C-c, it kills the ssh connection.  The ideal behavior would be to kill just the process that is running on the remote host.  I know, it sounds like I'm being picky here.  I'm  just hoping for it to work under Cygwin the way it does under Unix/Linux.

Comment: @ak2 - I think I will give the latest snapshot a try.  Thank you and vpit3833 for the help.  I'll report back soon.

Comment: Cygwin 1.7.8 with that fix was released yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a problem with the Command Prompt as a tty. I had problems sending the correct signals to the emacs shell inside Cygwin and Cygwin in general, so I found this program called puttycyg. Putty has a great shell and I wanted something like that for Cygwin, so I use this: http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/.

I created a shortcut on my desktop to make it easier to get to. You can create a session and call it "cygwin" from there and then make a shortcut to the executable and use `-load "cygwin"`.